# open data for plant disease?

Tags: data-request, agriculture, disease

I'm looking for an open data to use for detecting crop disease based on weather data. For example, to predict late blight disease for potato crop.
A dataset where given daily hourly temperature, humidity and rainfall there is a label that expresses whether the disease manifests or not

Answer (score 0):

A starting point (hence, partially answering your question) might be the EPPO Global Database which is maintained by the Secretariat of the European and Mediterranean Plant Protection Organization (EPPO).

It provides pest-specific information that has been produced or collected by EPPO and also offers an API. See

https://gd.eppo.int